# jQuery .append() and linebreaks

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery `.append()` to build part of a website with data I get from a JSON string. I'm trying to get some content on 2 separate lines, but I can't seem to get it to work.

This is what I've tried:

```
$('<p/>', { text: 'text before break <br /> text after break' }).appendTo(target);
//output: text before break <br /> text after break

$('<p/>', { text: 'text before break \n text after break' }).appendTo(target);
//output: text before break  text after break
```

Is there any way to get the `br` tag to work within `.append()`? Or should I scan the string first and slice it at the `br` tag, so that I can append it piece by piece?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `html`:

```
$('<p/>', { html: 'text before break <br /> text after break' }).appendTo(target);
```

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/gJqjT/

When you use`text` it basically escapes characters like `<` and `>` so it ends up outputting `&lt;br /&gt;` but when you use `html` it doesn't do that.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. I wasn't aware of the `html` option.

Answer (score 1):

Use `html` instead of `text` - it allows you to use any HTML there